# get joomla post image

Tags: php, wordpress, joomla, joomla2.5

I can not write good English.I use joomla 2.5 and i want to convert to wprd press.

I Writing a plugin for this action and I was able to transfer the content and the categories.

But i can not transfer image of content from joomla to wp!this is my code :

```
<?php
require_once 'wp-blog-header.php';
require_once 'wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php';
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
global $wpdb;
$wp_cat_id = array('11' => '74', '12' => '174', ....);

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "....", "...") or die(mysql_error());

$db = mysql_select_db('tebroomc_tebnew');
mysql_query("set character_set_results='utf8'");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `bme5k_categories` WHERE `parent_id` = 1 AND `level` = 1 AND `published` != -2 AND `metadesc` != ''") or die(mysql_error());

while ($root_cat = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `bme5k_categories` WHERE `parent_id` =" . $root_cat->id . " AND `level` = 2 AND `published` != -2") or die(mysql_error());

    $my_cat = $root_cat->id;
//    $wp_root_cat_id = wp_insert_category($my_cat);

    $root_cat_posts_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `bme5k_content` WHERE `catid` = " . $root_cat->id . " ") or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($root_cat_posts_sql) > 0) {
        while ($posts = mysql_fetch_object($root_cat_posts_sql)) {

            $my_post = array(
                'post_title' => $posts->title,
                'post_content' => $posts->introtext,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_author' => 1,
                'post_category' => array($wp_cat_id[$my_cat]),
                'post_date'      =>$posts->publish_up
            );
            wp_insert_post($my_post);
        }
    }

    while ($sub_cat = mysql_fetch_object($result2)) {
        $my_cat = $sub_cat->id;

        $sub_cat_posts_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `bme5k_content` WHERE `catid` = " . $sub_cat->id . " ") or die(mysql_error());
        if (mysql_num_rows($sub_cat_posts_sql) > 0) {
            while ($posts = mysql_fetch_object($sub_cat_posts_sql)) {
                $my_post = array(
                    'post_title' => $posts->title,
                    'post_content' => $posts->introtext,
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'post_author' => 1,
                    'post_category' => array($wp_cat_id[$my_cat]),
                    'post_date'      =>$posts->publish_up
                );
                wp_insert_post($my_post);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I put this code in word press root site.Now I want to know,when i read a content from joomla and i have transfer the content into the word press,how can i get image of that post ?

Answer (score 0):

This really depends.
Usually Joomla does not map the images in the db, they are just inserted in the markup.
If you copy the /images folder over to wordpress, they may work right away.

It is however possible that in the `images` field of the `#__content` table some images are set, although it was a feature hardly ever used on J2.5 so it's unlikely. Anyway, should they be used, you will still find them in the /images folder.

The typical content of the field in Joomla 2.5 is:

```
{"image_intro":"","float_intro":"","image_intro_alt":"","image_intro_caption":"","image_fulltext":"","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"","image_fulltext_caption":""}
```

In order to read it, simply create an object with

```
$images = json_decode($posts->images)
```

then you can use

```
$images->image_intro
```

etc.

Comment: I don't know why you say it's hardly ever used, actually from what I can tell based on questions I get a lot of people like having standardized layouts with images.

Comment: Maybe it's something local to Italy, of all the 2.5 sites I've seen,  not one used content->images; the first I've seen was on J3.